# Saving a field of type 'text_format' as a theme settings variable

Tags: 8, forms

I try to add a text area with wysiwyg editor in the theme setting.

If i use `'#type' => 'textfield'`, it works :

[image]

If I use `'#type' => 'text_format'`, the text is saved but i don’t see it as default value :

[image]

If I revert back to `'#type' => 'textfield'`, i can see this :

[image]

I guess it is related to the text_format form which is stored as an array ?

How can I use `text_format` in theme settings ?

Full code in mytheme.theme

```
function MYTHEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {

  $form['mytheme_texte_presentation'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'text_format',
    '#title'         => t('Test theme settings'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('mytheme_texte_presentation'),
    '#description'   => t("lorem ipsum"),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text format fields are considered to be a compound field (meaning that multiple values are stored for the one field -- the value and the format).

If you inspect the value of `mytheme_texte_presentation`, you'll find an array that looks something like this `array => ['value' => '<val>', 'format' => 'html_restreint']`.

If you look at the [docs for text_format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21src%21Element%21TextFormat.php/class/TextFormat/8.2.x), you'll see that there is a `#format` attribute.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$texte_presentation = theme_get_setting('mytheme_texte_presentation');
$form['mytheme_texte_presentation'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'text_format',
    '#title'         => t('Test theme settings'),
    '#default_value' => $texte_presentation['value'],
    '#format'        => $texte_presentation['format'],
    '#description'   => t("lorem ipsum"),
  );
```

**Note:** *This is untested code. You may need to tweak this a bit to make it functional.*

Comment: Thank you. I understand how it works now. I should have dumped all the variables before asking. The array `theme_get_setting('mytheme_texte_presentation')` was correct but i had a PHP error and `$texte_presentation['value']` was null.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got things sorted. If you provide the correct format, I'll update my answer for anyone who finds this in the future.

Comment: How do you then display this in your twig template?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary. Drupal will automatically render all of the form elements. Manually rendering it via the template is just asking for trouble.